# PM2 - Specify script command in config file

Tags: node.js, npm, pm2

I am trying to configure pm2 to use the JSON ecosystem configuration, so that the Docker container can utilize this configuration for multiple apps. In order to have optimal flexibility for the end user, I would like to support package.json scripts instead of running files.

This is how such a configuration file looks like:

```json
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "name": "frontend",
      "cwd": "/apps/frontend",
      "script": "npm",
      "args": "serve"
    },
    {
      "name": "backend",
      "cwd": "/apps/backend",
      "script": "npm",
      "args": "start"
    }
  ]
}
```

When reading other posts, it is possible to start pm2 processes with alternative script commands using CLI. Since my set-up runs in a docker container, I cannot use this as I am stuck to the configuration file and pm2-runtime.

While digging a little deeper, I noticed it always executes the command 'start'. So for the back-end app, this works fine. However, for the front-end app this command is different.

Has anyone achieved to use a configuration file for pm2 and successfully specifying a different script command from the package.json file?